# Capturing Group Regex Javascript match returns two values why?

Tags: javascript, regex

Why does 
`"abcabcabc".match(/(abc){3}/);`

return two entries `["abcabcabc", "abc"]`? both "abcabcabc" and "abc"

similarly,

`["1234", "1234"]`

Comment: Because the _first_ value is what the whole regex matches, every following corresponds to a match group

Comment: Are you asking why the TC39 committee decided to do this (which we cannot answer), or are you asking what the meaning of these values is (which is explained in the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match#Return_value)) ?

Comment: `(abc){3}` holds one `abc` sequence in first capturing group which is also last.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every regexp has an implicit capturing group around it, which is stored in result 0.

The second result comes from your capturing group `(abc)`. Most regexp implementations only keep the last match of that capturing group.

Answer (score 0):

> [`/(abc){3}/`](https://regex101.com/r/CCEmZ4/1):
>
> - 1st Capturing Group `(abc){3}`
>
>   `{3}` Quantifier — Matches exactly 3 times
>
>   A repeated capturing group will only capture the last iteration. Put a capturing group around the repeated group to capture all iterations or use a non-capturing group instead if you're not interested in the data.
>
>   `abc` matches the characters `abc` literally (case sensitive)

So the first value is the whole match, i.e. `"abcabcabc"`.

The second value is the last iteration captured by `(abc)`, i.e. `"abc"`.